# Why can't I match the last part of my regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to match a sentence with an optional end `'other (\\w+)'`. For example, the regular expression should match both sentence as follows and extract the word 'things':

- The apple and other things.
- The apple is big.

I wrote a regular expression as below. However, I got a result `(None,)`. If I remove the last `?`. I will get the right answer. Why?

```
>>> re.search('\w+(?: other (\\w+))?', 'A and other things').groups()
(None,)
>>> re.search('\w+(?: other (\\w+))', 'A and other things').groups()
('things',)
```

Comment: Because with "?" you are expecting more word after "things"

Comment: ? causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE.(From python website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule for regular expression searches is that they produce the ***leftmost** longest* match.  Yes, it tries to give you longer matches if possible, but most importantly, when it finds the *first* successful match, it will stop looking further.

In the first regular expression, the leftmost point where `\w+` matches is `A`.  The optional portion doesn't match there, so it's done.

In the second regular expression, the parenthesized expression is mandatory, so `A` is not a match.  Therefore, it continues looking.  The `\w+` matches `and`, then the second `\\w+` matches `things`.

---

Note that for regular expressions in Python, especially those containing backslashes, it's a good idea to write them using [`r'raw strings'`](/q/2081640/1157100).

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
re.search(r'\w+(?: other (\w+))?', 'A and other things').group()
```

You will see what is happening. Since anything after `\w+` is optional your `search` matches first word `A`.

As per [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `.groups()`
>
> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern.

And your `search` call doesn't return any subgroup hence you get:

```
re.search(r'\w+(?: other (\w+))?', 'A and other things').groups()
(None,)
```

**To solve your problem** you can use this alternation based regex:

```
r'\w+(?: other (\w+)|$)'
```

**Examples:**

```
>>> re.search(r'\w+(?: other (\w+)|$)', 'A and other things').group()
'and'
>>> re.search(r'\w+(?: other (\w+)|$)', 'The apple is big').group()
'big'
```